# In MS Access 2010 I'm trying to ignore a duplicate entry in a control

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to ignore duplicate entries in specific text fields on a form. So, for example, I have 3 fields for seal entry. If the person scans a seal twice, it will ignore the duplicate and keep the focus on the field until a different number is entered. I cobbled together some code that works for the first and second entry, but not the third. When I debug it seems to be finding a duplicate number even though I'm entering in a different one.

```
Private Sub Seal2_AfterUpdate()

If Seal2.Value = Seal1.Value Or Seal3.Value Then
    Seal2.Value = Null
    Seal1.SetFocus
    Seal2.SetFocus
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Seal3_AfterUpdate()

If Seal3.Value = Seal1.Value Or Seal2.Value Then
    Seal3.Value = Null
    Seal1.SetFocus
    Seal3.SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating the `Or` wrong. It's evaluating after the `Seal2.Value = Seal1.Value`.

So what you have done in that if statement is equivalent to

```
If (Seal3.Value = Seal1.Value) Or Seal2.Value Then
```

And since Seal2 has a value, it is evaluating to `True`

You want something more like:

```
If (Seal3.Value = Seal1.Value) Or (Seal3.Value = Seal2.Value) Then
```

Also, you seem to be setting focus to one field and then another. You probably want to only go to one unless you are trying to fire off triggers/events when you get/lose focus in each one; however, if you are doing that you might be playing with fire

In the end your if blocks probably want to look like this:

```
If (Seal2.Value = Seal1.Value) Or (Seal2.Value = Seal3.Value) Then
    Seal2.Value = Null
    Seal2.SetFocus
End If
```

and

```
If (Seal3.Value = Seal1.Value) Or (Seal3.Value = Seal2.Value) Then
    Seal3.Value = Null
    Seal3.SetFocus
End If
```

Finally, if you find that you have to expand beyond 3 fields, you may want take a slightly different approach that would be more scalable. E.g., Building up a list in memory, sorting and filtering it. But for 3 or 4 items you can get away with what you have already.